# Multiple checkbox select for Fullcalendar eventRender

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar

**Over my fullcalendar I have a few checkboxes, which I want to be react like a filter. 
In short: I want to filter for one, all, three, two (multiple)... and so on.**

I came this far, that I can select one Checkbox, and it's return the right Events, but it's not working for two ore more checkboxes, of course.
But I don't know, how to do this! My Javascript skill is not so good.

I fetch the Events with a Json File, which I created with Ruby on Rails 4 in the Model. But I don't want to split this Json. So I searching for a full Javascript version.

I think, the code will better show, what I mean.

**Html:**

```
<input id="hamburg" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select" type="checkbox" value="Hamburg">Hamburg</input>
<input id="schleswig-holstein" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select" type="checkbox" value="Schleswig-Holstein">Schleswig-Holstein</input>

<input id="party" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select"  type="checkbox" value="Party">Party</input>
<input id="concert" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select" type="checkbox" value="Concert">Concert</input>
<input id="festival" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select" type="checkbox" value="Festival">Festival</input>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[class=event_filter_box]').change(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
  });
});


$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Party Event in Hamburg',
      start: '2015-11-11',
      address_city: 'Hamburg',
      kind: 'Party',
    }, 
    {
      title: 'Conzert Event in Hamburg',
      start: '2015-11-10',
      address_city: 'Hamburg',
      kind: 'Concert',
    }, 
    {
      title: 'Festival Event in Schleswig-Holstein',
      start: '2015-11-08',
      end: '2015-11-12',
      address_city: 'Schleswig-Holstein',
      kind: 'Festival',
    }, 
  ],
  defaultView: "basicWeek",
  eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
    if ($('input[id=hamburg]').is(':checked')) {
      return ['all', event.address_city].indexOf($('#hamburg').val()) >= 0
    } else if ($('input[id=schleswig-holstein]').is(':checked')) {
      return ['all', event.address_city].indexOf($('#schleswig-holstein').val()) >= 0
    } else if ($('input[id=party]').is(':checked')) {
      return ['all', event.kind].indexOf($('#party').val()) >= 0
    } else if ($('input[id=concert]').is(':checked')) {
      return ['all', event.kind].indexOf($('#concert').val()) >= 0
    } else if ($('input[id=festival]').is(':checked')) {
      return ['all', event.kind].indexOf($('#festival').val()) >= 0
    }
  },
});
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/angel_crawford/pen/mezvVW)

How has the Javascript to be, for a multiple Select? Thank's before =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gohrbk41/1/

I changed the HTML a little bit, adding tags for data-type to differentiate between city and kind

```
<!-- I added data-type to the checkboxes -->
<input id="hamburg" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select" type="checkbox" value="Hamburg" data-type="address_city">Hamburg</input>
<input id="schleswig-holstein" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select" type="checkbox" value="Schleswig-Holstein" data-type="address_city">Schleswig-Holstein</input>

<input id="party" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select"  type="checkbox" value="Party" data-type="kind">Party</input>
<input id="concert" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select" type="checkbox" value="Concert" data-type="kind">Concert</input>
<input id="festival" class="event_filter_box" name="event_filter_select" type="checkbox" value="Festival" data-type="kind">Festival</input>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

And for the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[class=event_filter_box]').change(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
  });
});


$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Party Event in Hamburg',
      start: '2015-11-11',
      address_city: 'Hamburg',
      kind: 'Party',
    }, 
    {
      title: 'Conzert Event in Hamburg',
      start: '2015-11-10',
      address_city: 'Hamburg',
      kind: 'Concert',
    }, 
    {
      title: 'Festival Event in Schleswig-Holstein',
      start: '2015-11-08',
      end: '2015-11-12',
      address_city: 'Schleswig-Holstein',
      kind: 'Festival',
    }, 
  ],
  defaultView: "basicWeek",
  eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
      var display = true;
      var addresses = [];
      var kinds = [];
      // Find all checkbox that are event filters that are enabled
      // and save the values.
      $("input[name='event_filter_select']:checked").each(function () {
          // I specified data-type attribute in above HTML to differentiate
          // between locations and kinds of events.

          // Saving each type separately
          if ($(this).data('type') == 'address_city') {
              addresses.push($(this).val());
          }
          else if ($(this).data('type') == 'kind') {
              kinds.push($(this).val());
          }
      });

      // If there are locations to check
      if (addresses.length) {
          display = display && addresses.indexOf(event.address_city) >= 0;
      }

      // If there are specific types of events
      if (kinds.length) {
          display = display && kinds.indexOf(event.kind) >= 0;
      }

      return display;
  },
});
```

Comment: The code works perfect, thank you =) And I understand the code, too. With your Html, I can easily add more and more.