# Is there a way to toggle events visibility based on className FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I was wondering if there was a way using Full Calendar to show/hide elements based on the className of that event.

The exact situation is I have a checkbox (let's say #daytimeEvent) and I'd like to toggle the visibility of event htat has class daytime in the array....

I tried this so far but it seems to completely remove the events from the calendar without the possibility to get them back after....

Here is my current code:

```
$('#daytimeEvent').on('change', function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      // That part doesn't work
      calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent');  
    }
   else
   {
      // This seems to destroy the event without having the opportunity to toggle the visibility back after
      calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(event){
         return $.inArray('daytime', event.className)
      });
   }
}
```

I've crawled google and it seems like I'm not the only person with this problem but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: There are a few answers on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/36851477/5360631, http://stackoverflow.com/a/33635079/5360631 that use checkboxes for filtering. They don't use the class names but should be easily adaptable to do so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution (thanks to @smcd for the reference). The good way to do this is in the [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) method of your calendar. I put my logic in there and then did this:

```
$('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
     // your init [...] then
     eventRender: function(event, element) {
            // Array that will store accepted classes
            var eventAcceptedClasses = [];
            if ($('.daytime-events-checkbox').is(':checked')){
                eventAcceptedClasses.push('daytime-events');
            }
            if ($('.nighttime-events-checkbox').is(':checked')){
                eventAcceptedClasses.push('nighttime-events');
            }
            displayEvent = false;
            event.className.forEach(function(element){
                if ($.inArray(element, eventAcceptedClasses) != -1){
                    displayEvent = true;
                }
            });
            return displayEvent;
        }
});
```

Then, the things to do is just to use the [rerenderEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/) method in your event listener like this below.

```
$('.events-filter-checkbox').on('change', function(){
    calendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});
```

You cannot hide and show event on demande, but you can rerender which is quite flexible and fast.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake you have is how you're checking for the class existence:

```
$.inArray('.daytime', event.className)
```

There is no string `.daytime` inside the `className`, you should check for `daytime` instead (without the `.`):

```
$.inArray('daytime', event.className)
```

Comment: It would be better indeed and would work for the remove, but no way to toggle them to re-appear after...

Comment: You could have an array somewhere in the outer context into which you will save this data before removing it and then restore it when you need it.

Comment: I tought about this but I'm not sure it would redraw properly. Also, I have a few other checkboxes, so performance-wise I don't think it's the best idea, but I might have to if I find no other answer...

Comment: Good luck, sorry I can't be of more help, I'm not familiar with fullcalendar enough to see an appropriate solution.

Comment: thanks alot for your help anyways I might end up doing just this. I'm thinking 5 diferent array that I would merge depending on what is checked and not and redraw the event board everytime...

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answers are a bit old so, the new approach to solve this issue, is using [batchRendering](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-batchRendering)